# Simulating GPS Data to Android AVD Not Working

Tags: android, eclipse, gps, android-virtual-device

I’m hoping someone can help me with an issue I’m having with sending emulated GPS data to an Android AVD in Eclipse. If I run the application on a real device everything works fine, but when I attempt to uses the built in emulator in eclipse nothing will happen. I have also tried telneting into the AVD and issuing the geo fix command. Below is the code I am using although I don’t think there is anything wrong with it if it works on the real device

The manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.TestGoogleMaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="10" android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TestingGoogleMapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   </application>
</manifest>
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
</LinearLayout>
```

The Main Code

```
package net.TestGoogleMaps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestingGoogleMapsActivity extends Activity 
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LocationManager locationManager; 
        String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE; 
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context); 
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); 
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false); 
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false); 
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true); 
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW); 
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true); 

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); 


        updateWithNewLocation(location);


        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10,    
                                               locationListener); 
    }



    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() { 
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
          updateWithNewLocation(location); 
        } 

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){ 
          updateWithNewLocation(null); 
        } 

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ } 
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,  
                                    Bundle extras){ } 
      };




    public void updateWithNewLocation(Location location)
    {

        Context contextApp = getApplicationContext();

        String text ;
        int duration = 2000;

        if(location == null)
        {
            text ="Null Location";

        }
        else
        {
            text = "Lat : " + location.getLatitude() + " Lon: " + location.getLongitude();
        }

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(contextApp, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }   
}
```

I will also get the following error sometimes when simulating the GPS data from eclipse to the device in the LogCat tab of eclipse.

```
05-31 02:31:35.158: E/InputQueue-JNI(347): channel '406e6640  net.TestGoogleMaps/net.TestGoogleMaps.TestingGoogleMapsActivity (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've read this elsewhere. I think that this is a known bug. [Source](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13046)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I known your problem, You can set your current (long/lag) manually at

DDMS->Devices->Emulator Control->Location Controls->Manual->input (Long/Lag) and SEND

Answer (score 0):

As Tanvir Ahmed stated, it look like [its a bug (Source)](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13046). I also stumbled over this for over a day now.
What you can try is, to use "Google APIs - API Level 10" instead of "Android 2.3.3" for the AVM.